# JUnit java IDEA, class not found

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I try to run 'All Tests', but everytime I catch issue like 
Class not found: "com.desmond.testing.UserServiceTest"

I think I have a problem with my IDEA, because when I gave my project other people they said it works. Where can I have a issue with my Intellij IDEA.

Look in screenshot with my hierarchy project.
I sought same problems in stackoverflow and other places in WEB, but nothing help me

This is my first project with hibernate and junit, please help me :)

http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1014158761181

Comment: I dont trust external sites for pictures, can you please include the picture directly in the question?

Comment: I cant because my rating is less then 10, sorry. Maybe I can load my picture on other hosting? If you say where

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling the class before you run it, or running `Make` (ctrl+F9 on Windows).